# Is it bad practice to submit() a form when a user selects an option from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit, onchange

Currently im working on a project to create a booking website.

- I have a number of dropdowns whose options are generated using php to send sql queries to my database.
- Options of certain dropdowns are dependant on what the user has selected in another dropdown, thus i have to submit the form to update the $_POST superglobal onChange.
- Is this constant submitting of the form bad practice and if so what other methods could i use to have dropdowns that are dependant on other dropdowns (whilst also querying my database). (One issue im having with my current method is when form.submit() the page reloads an goes to the top of the page)

THANKS!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. While your question is valid, it is generally a matter of opinion on best/bad practices. Please note these types of questions are considered off-topic for SO. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before asking a question.

Comment: Use AJAX - and asynchronously call your database with the user's input (whether it be a drop-down or some other control) and populate/display additional controls with the response.

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The statement " i have to submit the form to update the $_POST" seems to be the root of your issue.

Comment: Remember that in some browsers, every time an option is selected they dispatch a change event. So if users are navigating using the keyboard, you may send a lot of unnecessary requests.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, being new to SO and web developing (started 6 weeks ago) i appreciate the advice and will avoid 'off-topic' posts. Looks like i need to take a look at AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that with each round-trip to the web server, the client's web page has to be completely re-rendered, plus you have to send all of your form data every time.

Instead, use AJAX to only transmit and query for data you need.  In this way also, the page won't need to be re-rendered.  The performance difference will be significant.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, it is opinion-based question and that every good rule have even better exception, so no universal truth can be given as answer here.

Also submit from dropdown can be confusing often and can have other unintended consequencies sometimes.

I solved similar problem with serie of pages, where was not many dropdowns, but one serie of link (a href) on each of them (sometimes even paginated list, if there was too much options on this level). I also displayed current progress as text on top of each such page.

To go not to top of page, but somwhere else you can use the A NAME=something target at selected place and go to PATH/PAGE#something